# How to force GCC to use ld.gold if real-ld executable exists in compiler search path?

Tags: gcc, gold-linker

I've found out that when GCC (tried on GCC 4.8 and GCC 6.4) finds `real-ld` executable in its search path, it is silently ignoring `-fuse-ld=...` option, and use `real-ld` instead of appropriate linker.

```
$ echo "int main(){}" > script.c
$ ln -s /usr/bin/ld real-ld
$ gcc -fuse-ld=gold -B$PWD script.c
$ readelf --string-dump=.note.gnu.gold-version a.out
readelf: a.out: Warning: Section '.note.gnu.gold-version' was not dumped because it does not exist!
```

Normally, without `real-ld` it will work as expected:

```
$ echo "int main(){}" > script.c
$ gcc -fuse-ld=gold script.c
$ readelf --string-dump=.note.gnu.gold-version a.out

String dump of section '.note.gnu.gold-version':
  [     c]  GNU
  [    10]  gold 1.12
```

[Documentation of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) suggests that `gold` linker will be used.

[Documentation of collect2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.4.0/gccint/Collect2.html) does not say anything about `-fuse-ld` feature...

Comment: Very likely a GCC bug

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr It is not possible [2]. This is a feature.**

I've dug deep into GCC's [collect2.c source code](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/f2b648ddec0a95529d90afb5becaa0dbe0530f75/gcc/collect2.c#L1098), it's history, and [collect2 documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Collect2.html#Collect2), and came into conclusion that, based on those documents, it is expected behavior that `real-ld` takes precedence over all other binaries [1].

However, logic of searching *real* ld, when `-fuse-ld=...` is enabled, is vague and does not have reflection in documentation...

Based on source code, as far as I understand C language, `-fuse-ld=...` feature is effective only when collect2 tries to search for `ld`.

[1] One exception is when GCC is compiled with `--with-ld=...`, but only for non-crosscompilers. It gives nothing if one cannot rebuild GCC (or uses crosscompiler).

[2] Not entirely true. Just came into hackish idea to create own `real-ld` that would exec `ld.gold`, and modify compiler search path (using `-B`, instead of using `-fuse-ld=...`):

```
$ cat /path/to/real-ld/real-ld
#!/bin/sh
exec ld.gold "$@"

$ gcc -B /path/to/real-ld/ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove real-ld and in it's place have ld. pointing to the linker you want to use. This way -fuse-ld=gold will work if there is a ld.gold, same for ld.bfd.